# creating a display function

Tags: c++, function

I am working on this for an assignment and cannot figure out how to even get started to write the function for the following program.

The code given is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "BACCOUNT.H"
using namespace std;

void display(const bankAccount & anAcct)
{

}


int main()
{
bankAccount a("Annie Hill", 123.00);
bankAccount b("Becker" , 45.60);
display(a);
display(b);
return 0;
}
```

and I need to write a display function that will make the name and balance for bankAccount a and bankAccount b display.

I've been working on this for about 3 days now, and cannot figure out how to even start.

my output needs to be:

```
bankAccount: Hill, Annie, $123.00
bankAccount: Becker, Bob, $45.00
```

what I've got so far is;

```
anAcct.name();
string name = anAcct.name();
int space = name.find("5"); 
name.substr(0, 5);
name.substr(5, 9);
name.length();

cout << name;
```

Which I know is way off, I've just been trying trial and error.

Comment: What do you have for display so far? 3 days with empty display?

Comment: there is no question visible anymore. please rewrite your question or remove it

Answer (score 1):

You can overload << operator in your bankAccount class and let that operator print the content of your class from display function.
e.g. code for reference

```
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, bankAccount& a)
    {
      os << a.name() << ":" << a.accountBalance();
    }

    void display(const bankAccount & anAcct)
   {
     std::cout << anAcct;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

bankAccount is you class and you should have at leat 2 variables in it !. is the name and second will be the amount and you need a diolay() function that display those variable using getters

```
 void bankAccount::display(){
    std::cout << this->getname() <<this->getamount<< "$ "<< std::endl;
}
```

in the main function using a.display() and there you go